# Android implementing search in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, search, android-edittext, fragment

I am trying to add a search function in my ListFragment. I have done it in a standard Activity, but am trying to port it over to fragments.
What I am currently doing is this:

1. I have a Main.java that hosts the fragments.
2. I have a ListFrag.java that hosts the list array List.TERM with R.id.frag_list

My Main.java implements addTextChangedListener like this:

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
                                                                    // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int count, int after)
    {
    // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int before, int count)
    {
    textlength = et.getText().length();
    array_sort.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < List.TERM.length; i++)
    {
    if (textlength <= List.TERM[i].length())
    {
    if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
    (String)
    List.TERM[i].subSequence(0,
    textlength)))
    {array_sort.add(List.TERM[i]);
    }
    }
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (Main.this,
            R.layout.main,R.id.frag_list, array_sort));
    }
    });
```

and my main.xml is like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/searchbar"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="@string/prompt">
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    class="com.bernard.ListFrag" />
```

When I run the app, I click the editText. The instant I try to type a letter, the app crashes with error log:

```
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.bernard.Main$1.onTextChanged(Main.java:54)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8105)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8152)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8532)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:892)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:669)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:431)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:369)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5025)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-11 12:59:57.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My guesses for such an error are:

1. I should be implementing the editText and text listeners under the fragment and not Main.java.
2. I am not calling the new list from Main.java, hence a NullPointerException.

Anyone have suggestions to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you point out which line in Main.java is line #54?  A cursory look at onTextChanged reveals there are several places where a NullPointerException might be thrown so without that info it's difficult to say for sure which one is actually throwing the one from your stack trace.

Comment: it refers to: lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it myself! Thanks Nick for your help too :D

It's a little rough, but it works. If you think you have a better solution, do share!

So what I did was create a list fragment view a fragment view as according to the example in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

The trick is, in ListFrag.java, I simply implemented everything in my original activity under the onCreateView.
The important parts are below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    lv = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    final ArrayList <String>ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    et = (EditText) V.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    final String[] words = list.TERM;
    // Populate list with our static array of titles.
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, list.TERM));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
                                                                    // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int count, int after)
    {
    // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int before, int count)
    {
    textlength = et.getText().length();
    array_sort.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
    if (textlength <= words[i].length())
    {
    if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
    (String)
    words[i].subSequence(0,
    textlength)))
    {array_sort.add(words[i]);
    }
    }
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, array_sort));
    }
    });

    //Intent after selection is made
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String name = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            for (int index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
            {
                if (name.equals(words[index]))
                {
                    position = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            String d1  = words[position];
            ar.add(d1.toString()); 

            showDetails(position);

        }
    });



    return V;
}
```

And there you have it, full search on a listview inside a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.TERM.length; i++)
    {
    if (textlength <= List.TERM[i].length())
    {
    if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
    (String)
    List.TERM[i].subSequence(0,
    textlength)))
    {array_sort.add(List.TERM[i]);
    }
    }
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (Main.this,
            R.layout.main,R.id.frag_list, array_sort));
    }
    });
```

with:

```
           // reuse the existing adapter instead of creating a new one:
           ArrayAdapter<String> ad = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListView().getAdapter();
           ad.clear();
           for (int i = 0; i < List.TERM.length; i++) {
              if (textlength <= List.TERM[i].length()) {
                 if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                       (String)
                             List.TERM[i].subSequence(0,
                                   textlength))) {
                    ad.add(List.TERM[i]);
                 }
              }
           }
           ad.notifyDataSetChanged(); // tell the ListView to update
```

Comment: Oh also make sure that wherever you instantiate your ArrayAdapter, you are passing in a concrete instance like new ArrayList<String>() as the list argument.

Comment: Clarification on the above comment:  If you just pass in an array like so many ArrayAdapter tutorials show, you get an ArrayAdapter whose model is frozen and cannot be reused as shown above.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! sorry, I don't really understand. meaning I should do that in Main.java or ListFrag.java?
and in line #2 of your proposed solution, I get "The method getListView() is undefined for the type Main"

Comment: I was assuming from the name of the class that ListFrag.java extended ListFragment, which would provide access to getListView().  I now see that this code is in Main.java, which is a little confusing to me.  You can try replacing getListView() with your lv variable, but without seeing how it is being initialized I am dubious about whether or not lv is a valid instance.

Comment: haha thats my main concern. Main.java gives me access to R.id.EditText01 but ListFrag.java does not. So I want to get a new list based on my input in EditText01, and transfer that to ListFrag. I am thinking of implementing EditText in the fragment instead... but just wanna know if it can still work in Main.java

Comment: You should create some sort of setModel(...) method in your ListFrag class.  Generate the new list based on EditText01, etc. from within your Main.java and then invoke your setModel(...) method on your ListFrag instance from there, passing in the new list.  The body of your setModel(...) method would essentially just be the snippet I posted above.